# Why does mysql command over ssh does not prompt for password?

Tags: mysql, bash, ssh

I'm attempting to run a command like the following:

`ssh user@host 'mysql -u dbuser -p database < ~/data.sql'`

I'm expecting it to prompt me a password like it normally would if you're on that host.

However, it does not do that. Is there an ssh argument I'm missing or something?

Another thing to note is that if you remove the `< ~/data.sql`, the prompt does appear as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a pseudo-terminal so that `mysql` can read from `/dev/tty` instead of standard input:

```
ssh -t user@host 'mysql -u dbuser -p database < ~/data.sql'
```

Comment: Any suggestions of where to go to learn about managing standard input vs tty?

Comment: No, sorry, I have no idea where that would be discussed in detail.